# how to tune Mysql when storage engine is MyISAM

Tags: mysql, isam

MyISAM queries results too slow,What changes should i make,

**if** 
Ram 16GB
DB 500GB

```
mysql> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'key%'

+------------------------+-------------+
| Variable_name          | Value       |
+------------------------+-------------+
| Key_blocks_not_flushed | 0           | 
| Key_blocks_unused      | 275029      | 
| Key_blocks_used        | 3316428     | 
| Key_read_requests      | 11459264178 | 
| Key_reads              | 3385967     | 
| Key_write_requests     | 91281692    | 
| Key_writes             | 27930218    | 
+------------------------+-------------+
```

Comment: How much RAM?  Any InnoDB tables, too?

Comment: 16gb RAM with 637 MyISAM Tables and 67 Innodb Tables , 21 MEMORY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After subtracting off enough room for the actual sizes of the MEMORY tables and any applications that are running on the same machine, give 10% of the remaining RAM to `key_buffer_size` to 10% and `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 35% of RAM.  That should be a good first cut at the main memory users.

The `Key_reads / Key_read_requests` says that `key_buffer_size` is big enough.  `Key_blocks_used * 1024 / key_buffer_size` will give you an upper bound on what you need currently.

If you have made any other changes in my.cnf, let's see them.

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory

Comment: so in your opinion it's is not need to be tune up ?

Comment: False.  You have not provided details about InnoDB usage, nor the value of key_buffer_size.  The two percentages I provided are a pretty-safe first guess at what will be good.